# How to store unlimited tags in database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, tags, nosql

I am working on a website which asks user to give tag's to their newly created content (similar to stackoverflow Tags). But how to store this tags? , if mysql database used then I have to set limit on number of columns and number of tags itself. Since I wish to give unlimited tagging option to user which approach should be followed?

Comment: What if I go with limited tags let's say they are 20 in total. Then I need to create 20 columns and suppose some user's gave less tags (Most of the time this will be the case). In this scenario most of the columns will be empty . What to do in this case , is it good design by the way to allow so much table entries empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a classic *n to m relation*. Like this

```
tags table
----------
id
name
...


content table
-------------
id
title
...

content_tags table
------------------
content_id
tag_id
```

To store multiple tags for a single content, add a record to the content_tags table for each tag you want it to have. Example:

```
content_tags table
------------------
content_id |  tag_id
1          |  2
1          |  5
1          |  1
```

To then get the tags of a content record do:

```
select t.*
from tags t
join content_tags ct on ct.tag_id = t.id
join content c on ct.content_id = c.id
where c.title = 'my content title'
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I go with limited tags let's say they are 20 in total. Then I need to create 20 columns and suppose some user's gave less tags (Most of the time this will be the case). In this scenario most of the columns will be empty . What to do in this case , is it good design by the way to allow so much table entries empty?

Comment: The design I mention in my answer is the one to choose for no matter how many tags, fixed or not. Well if there is max. only one tag per post then you would of course not do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is: make a separate table that you store the names of tags in. Then, you have to use a foreign key, and essentially, when they select tags, you have each entry link to the row in your tags table. That would allow you to store 'unlimited tags', as you could just keep adding to the tags table.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to approach this problem:

1. As the other answer suggests, create a `tags` table in the database specifically. This is the most traditional way of doing this. For example, wordpress has `tags` and `categories` table that link to the `posts` table where each post published by the user is stored.
2. Another way is to store it in a `json` field (nowadays most databases have it including mysql and pgsql) in the main table itself, instead of storing in a separate `tags` table. The advantage of this is that your queries will be faster as one join is eliminated. The disadvantage is that you won't get the usual benefits of normalization, i.e an efficient storage size.
3. Another quick and dirty, but "old school" way of doing this is to use a delimiter in a single memo or LOB field to store your tags. Using a comma delimiter, it will be something like: `html,css,javascript`, and then split using the delimiter whenever you want to process them. Of course, the obvious disadvantage is that you won't be able to use that delimiter (comma, in this example) as part of the tag.

Comment: The idea that eliminating JOINs somehow improves query performance is simply misguided